# Are these scratches on an induction plate cleanable?

Tags: kitchens, glass, scratches

I have an induction plate that works great for a few years now. It is surprisingly clean, all kind of burned food is easy to remove. It has, however, a few very small scratches and I would like to understand whether they are "cleanable", or whether this is a permanent change in the plate.

I would like to make it clear that this is really an aesthetic question - they are tiny and do not impact the functioning of the plate in any way. They are also real scratches, not fissures because something has fallen on the plate and broke it.

I understand that a scratch itself is not something that can be "cleaned" - it is more the nature of their color I want to understand (whether they can be turned into "transparent scratches" or whether there is something inside them I can clean.

The overall view of the plate:

[image]

I tried my best to take macro photos of the scratches to show their nature:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried the usual "products to clean indiction plates" and insisted on the scratches but besides making the rest of the plate shiny clean this did not help with the scratches.

Comment: Can you distinguish them from being grooves or ridges by running a fingernail across them? If they are grooves, then the dark material is baked on foodstuffs and can be dissolved eventually. Try some vinegar soaked into a rag and left on it for a while, so that the acid in the vinegar will dissolve the foodstuff. If they are ridges, get a razor blade scraper (like for paint on a window) and try to scrape them off.

Comment: @JRaef: they are grooves, so light that I can barely feel them with my fingernail. If you think that this could be burned up food then this is good news, I will try your solution. I was more worried (again, for purely silly and inconsequential aesthetic reasons) that this would rather be permanent glass modification (that the color in ingrained with the glass plate)